# Alternative / Similar to tag in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, tags

Is there any alternative to use like `tag` to property of UIView? The thing is I'd like to pass `UITextField` some `NSInteger`. Way to do is `tag`. But I want to pass 2 different `NSInteger`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass UITextField and add two NSInteger properties to the class.

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger y;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach any data to any object using an [Associative Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). This is a very handy approach. It even correctly handles memory management. I sometimes use a category to wrap these so I can create new properties on an existing class. For example, in one project I'd like every view controller to know about a special label (like how they all know about `navigationController`). I do it this way:

```
@interface UIViewController (MYSpecialViewController)
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) UILabel *specialLabel;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (MYSpecialViewController)
static const char kMySpecialLabelKey;

- (UILabel *)specialLabel
{
  return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kMySpecialLabelKey);
}

- (void)setSpecialabel:(UILabel *)value
{
  objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kMySpecialLabelKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

You can find a simple working example using a `UIAlertView` in the iOS5:PTL sample code for [Chapter 3](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch03/AssocRef/AssocRef/ViewController.m).

Comment: I made a couple of small edits, I hope you don't mind. Previously it would have used the static pointer value, which would be 0. Now it's a pointer to a static char, which will have a meaningful address.

Comment: @SedateAlien Thanks. You're completely correct. This was a bug in the code I was referencing (so I've now fixed my product code). The sample code referenced does it correctly. As you note, this should be a char, not a char*.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this -vs- subclassing?

Comment: pardon me, but how to add primitive data type ? such as NSInteger / int.

Comment: @Inafziger Subclassing has many limitations. Consider the above example. I want every UIViewController to have this functionality. Obviously I could make MYViewController and subclass from that, but what if I want UITableViewViewControllers, too? There's nowhere to inject the code in that case without duplicating the properties. (This was the exact reason for the code above, btw; it was originally a subclass.) This also works with classes that can't safely be subclassed, and with instances generated by the frameworks.

Comment: @HelmiB The best solution usually would be to wrap it in an NSNumber. But, you can also store anything that is the size of a pointer as long as you pass the behavior OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN. Just be careful that you know the correct size for a pointer (NSInteger and CGFloat are useful for this since they are always pointer-sized).

Comment: @RobNapier I got the error of doing so. could you please add up your answer to use NSInteger ?

Comment: Let me guess; you're running under ARC? You could add the required cast (__bridge id), but that's starting to get ugly if you don't deeply know what you're doing. It really takes an `id`, so pass one. Just wrap the integer in an NSNumber.

Comment: Associative references are more documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24

Answer (score 1):

Take the general, object-oriented solution, but remember you can a stuff lot of data into a tag:

```
- (uint32_t)pack:(uint16_t)a with:(uint16_t)b {

  return (uint32_t)(a << 16 | b);
}

- (uint16_t)getA:(uint32_t)pair {
    return (uint16_t)((pair & 0xffff0000) >> 16);
}

- (uint16_t)getB:(uint32_t)pair {
    return (uint16_t)(pair & 0xffff);
}

// use it

- (void)setupSomeView {

    someView.tag = [self pack:1024 with:2048];
}

- (IBAction)someControlEventHappened:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%d %d", [self getA:sender.tag], [self getB:sender.tag]);
}
```

Caveats:

1. @RobNapier's answer is more general, more correct.  The only
   advantage this way is that it's quick and dirty
2. Works for pairs of unsigned ints < 32k
3. Works NSInteger implementations >= 32 bits, which is everywhere, I think.